Catching ValidationFailedException in a listener or subscriber
I'm building a simple REST api with Symfony 7 and using MapRequestPayload attribute to automatically map request data into an object. Validation is also handled automatically with symfony/validator.
// a controller method
use App\Request\TestRequest

public function example(#[MapRequestPayload] TestRequest $testRequest): JsonResponse
{
  // validation is handled automatically, safely use $testRequest object...
}

This works great, except I would like to return a json response simpler than what symfony is automatically returning.
To do that, I've created a listener to catch ValidationFailedExceptions and set the response there. But apparently, my listener only gets handed a HttpException. In order to catch ValidationFailedException, I use getPrevious() method and check if it is a ValidationFailedException
public function onKernelException(ExceptionEvent $event)
{
    $exception = $event->getThrowable();
    $prevException = $exception->getPrevious();
    if ($exception instanceof HttpException && $prevException instanceof ValidationFailedException) {
    // create a custom json response using $prevException->getViolations()
    ...
}

This works, but since I'm new to Symfony, I'm not sure this is the right way or even a reliable way to achieve this.
Opinions?

I think that this solution is fine :)  I don't see any further processing, but you might want tu utilize ConstraintViolationListNormalizer if you plan on doing the mapping on frontend. This should be implemented in the default NormalizerInterface that you can inject in your handler constructor.
